# Swift get value of invisible tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

How to make all cells in a table is visible so that I can get all cell values? Right now, My table has 9 cells and only 4 cells shows on the initial screen, if I want to get another 5 cells I have to scroll the view. Using the getCellsData(), I can get the first 4 cells values, when I scroll down, I can give 5 cells but the former 4 values are gone. Is there any way to get 9 cells?

```
    func getCellsData(){
    for section in 0 ..< self.myTable.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0 ..< self.myTable.numberOfRowsInSection(section) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
            if let selectedCell = myTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? AddFollowTableViewCell {
                dictAnswer[row] = selectedCell.cellValue - 1
            }
        }
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addFollowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddFollowTableViewCell
    cell.questionView.text = listQuestion1[indexPath.row]
    cell.pickerDataSource = dictPicker[indexPath.row]!
    cell.answerPicker.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.answerText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddFollowUpViewController.pickerValueChange(_:)), forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
    return cell
}

func pickerValueChange(sender: UITextView) {
    // Get the sliders value
    let currentValue = sender.text
    let pickerRow = sender.tag
    // Do whatever you want with the value :)
    // And now the row of the slider!

    dictAnswer[currentValue] = pickerRow
    print(dictAnswer)
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    // selected value in Uipickerview in Swift
    let value=pickerDataSource[row]
```

//        array.append(value)
    }

Comment: Do not retrieve data from the **view** (table view cell), do it from the **model** (data source array)

Comment: My problem is I have a tableview with several cell, each cell has a pickerview from different datasource. What I want is get each cell pick value. Any suggestion?

Comment: Whenever the user has picked a value, save it in the data model.

Comment: How? Can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: The picker is a subview of the table view cell. Connect an action from the picker to the target view controller. When the action is called get the table view cell from the appropriate picker by calling `superView`. Then get the row which is the index of the corresponding item in the data source array and save the value.

Comment: What does the action means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112175/discussion-between-janice-zhan-and-vadian).

Comment: Picker views can be connected programmatically to an `IBAction` which is called when a particular event occurs for example `.ValueChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats possible, simply because the tableView doesn't store all cells. It uses a caching mechanism which only stores some cells, that are not visible, for reuse.

Why do you need all cells? Maybe you can achieve, what you're trying to do, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks.  
My problem is I have a tableview with several cell, each cell has a pickerview from different datasource. What I want is get each cell pick value. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you need the values before loading the cells ?. If you need before you can store them in a array when the values are calculated. 

If you don't need before you can save them in array when cells are constructed in the method " tableView func (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell"

Comment: I dont need those before loading. But the problem is the picker value in cell is changeable, and How can I get those changed values in view controller?

Comment: By "func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)" you you can get the value of each pickerView through its tag value

Comment: yes, I tried that. But how can I get all values for each picker in view controller?

Comment: I get all values from the method "tableView func (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell". In case any value in a cell is modified, I would update this value in array from  "func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)" function.

Comment: I cant understand that. Can you help me write the code? I have post the code for didSelectRow and cellForRowAtIndexPath. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112189/discussion-between-janice-zhan-and-oremag14jf).